# Why Vuforia AR not working in my device?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to Unity AR.I have completed an IOS app which is working with Vuforia plane detection and tested using ipad.Now I took the project and switched to android platform.When I installed and checked it is not detecting any plane.So I tried a sample program[[Link]](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/ground-plane-guide.html).Still it is not working.I checked the devices supported for Vuforia my device was there in the list Samsung Galaxy S7(SM-G930P).
I am using Unity 2017.3.0f3 and Vuforia Version 7.0.36.How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Unity to 2018.1.0f2 and Vuforia Version 7.1.34. Now it's working.